# How does an ISP block IP Addresses?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I live in the UK and my ISP BT has blocked the pirate bay. I know you can just use proxies. I thought I'd be smart and get the pirate bay IP and connect to it that way, but it turns out BT has blocked the pirate bays IP. So I was wondering how does an ISP block you from accessing IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is by definition on path to anything you access. It can just keep a list of IPs that they will not let you access and can hijack connections to them.

So for example when you connect to `192.0.2.1` they can just reply directly instead of letting the packets go to the real IP, and their reply is just a page displaying something like "site blocked etc".

Alternatively they could just not pass the packets forward and you would get a timeout. The gist of the matter is that since they are always on path **they can always just check the destination IP** in your packets.

Answer (score 0):

They Know each Root u go, logic compairs Target ip with blacklists! Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Considering all your traffic goes through your ISP, it's within their power to block anything or everything from their side.

Also take note, a websites "address" only exists in the pretty version(www.something.com) because it makes it easier to read for people, than a bunch of numbers(an IP).
But in practice, when you visit a website, the first is always converted into the latter, so there's no difference if you visit piratebay.com or whatever it's IP number is.